# Value of EditText in Fragment not Refreshing

Tags: android

I have a pretty simple use case:

- I have defined a Button and an EditText inside of a fragment.
- I have tied that Button action to a method in the fragment's activity.
- I want to update the text of the EditText from that method

My action method (in the fragment) is as follows:

```
public void notifyLaterAction(View view) {
    EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nextNotificationTime);
    editText.setText("Gotcha");
    String theText = editText.getText().toString();
    Log.d(LOG_PATH, theText);
}
```

After running, theText is "Gotcha," but the UI does not update.  Can anyone tell me what's going on here?

**Edit: Updated with additional code**

Here's the Button defined in the Fragment:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/notifyLaterButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
    android:onClick="notifyLaterAction"
    android:text="Ask Me Later" />
```

Here's the full stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: notifyLaterAction [class android.view.View]
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:472)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:857)
    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3963)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4654)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19438)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: notifyLaterAction [class android.view.View]
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:472)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:857)
    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3963)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4654)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19438)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Try to invalidate the view somehow

Comment: Please show more code. Where are you calling that action() method?

Comment: @joao2fast4u I am using the XML binding technique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have bind method from xml, then you need to call this from the **Activity class** which is having  that layout.

**Edit :** Previously I was totally wrong and sorry for directing you in wrong direction.

**1.)** If you have defined onClick in xml, then it must be in Activity.

**2.)** Even if you decide to have notifyLaterAction(View mView) method inside Activity. You can not access to

```
EditText editText = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.nextNotificationTime);
```

This will be always null, because mView is only for Button view, so that you can not use seText and getText methods.

**3.)** The only option we have here is to declare and initialize EditText and Button inside your fragment and use setOnClickListener method for button click event and make edit-text change inside it.

Comment: I am using the XML bind method.  I read in the Android documentation that you cannot use the XML bind technique to bind the action to the Fragment.  When I try this technique I get: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException.

Comment: Are you sure your layout and action(View view) are in same-fragment?    And can you please show us button attributes of xml?